# Cannot wrap my head around how cin.get and cout are working here

Tags: c++, iostream

I was going through iostreams on C++ annotations and came across copying cin stream to cout. My conventional wisdom says only one character should be printed by cout but rather cout prints entire line till I terminate it with newline or EOF.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace::std;

int main()
{
  while (true)
  {
    char c;

    cin.get(c);
    if (cin.fail())
      break;
    cout << c;

  }
}
```

Sample input/output:

```
   123456789
   123456789
```

Looking at the code I had expect only one character to be printed.

I think my understanding of streams may be fundamentally wrong. Can someone explain how exactly the cin and cout streams are behaving in this loop.

Comment: Why do you expect only one character to be printed?

Comment: `while (true)` repeats forever. `cin.fail()` causes return at the end of the stream.

Comment: How does cout get each character after I have input entire line in cin?

Comment: Ah, do you expect the `get` consumes the entire 123456789, and just gives you the first character?

Comment: Yes because cout << c;

Comment: Remove everything apart from `char c; cin.get(c); cout << c;`

Comment: In that case I had expect cin to get a character and put a character. So something like 11223344 for 1234 as input

Comment: Your code is actually the proper way to do user input. Regardless whether you are using `cin`, `fgets`, `scanf`, `getline`, etc... You simply set a continual loop, take input, validate the stream state (no `failbit` or `badbit`), or the function return in C, to verify the conversion (if any) and that the user didn't cancel input by generating a manual `EOF`, then apply any range or type validations required, and control termination of the loop in an orderly manner. If you approach input this way, you won't have any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Standard input is line-buffered and read as a stream.

When you press Enter, the entire line is put into the input buffer:

```
|'1'|'2'|'3'|'4'|'5'|'6'|'7'|'8'|'9'|'\n'|
```

Then `cin.get(c)` reads `'1'`, which `cout << c` prints, and the stream becomes

```
|'2'|'3'|'4'|'5'|'6'|'7'|'8'|'9'|'\n'|
```

and after the next iteration, reading `'2'` and printing that:

```
|'3'|'4'|'5'|'6'|'7'|'8'|'9'|'\n'|
```

and so on, until you reach the end of the line.
Then your program starts waiting for the next line of input.